# Apps Script CalendarApp createAllDayEvent creates event but it only displays "To:" in the calendar

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, calendar

I want to add events to my Google calendar based on data in my spreadsheet.  The names of the events and their dates will come from the spreadsheet.

Here is the table I want to process:
[image: image of table]

```
function myFunction() {


  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var calendarID = spreadsheet.getRange("D1").getValue();
  var eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarID);

  var dates = spreadsheet.getRange("A1:B11").getValues();
  var date = dates[0][0];
  var event = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().createAllDayEvent(date,new Date('3-19-2020'));

  for(x = 0; x < dates.length; x++) {

  }
}
```

But even when I try to execute all this without a loop I get this result:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I threw away this idea and started the same "project" with more familiar to me Java.

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter for the `createAllDayEvent(title, startDate, endDate)` method of the CalendarApp Class is the `title`  which must be a string data type.  JavaScript values can have different data types.  They can be a `string`, or an `object`, or a `Boolean`, or a `number`, or a `date`.  A date evaluates as an object when checking the data type with `typeof`. If the value for `date` is a date, then it's the wrong data type for the `title` parameter.  You can determine the data type with `typeof putSomethingHere`  So, I'd check the data type of `date` and convert it to a string if needed.

```
if (typeof date === 'object') {
  timeZone = Session.getScriptTimeZone();//Enter your timezone here
  date = Utilities.formatDate(date, timeZone, "yyyy-MM-dd");//Formats the date to a string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the `data table` you have posted, it seems that `A1` and `B1` are the **headers** for your spreadsheet and when you are trying to create an event, you are creating the `var date` with the `dates[0][0]` parameter, which is essentially represented by the headers.

What you can do instead is to update the range in order to not include the headers, like this: `var dates = spreadsheet.getRange("A2:B11").getValues();` **OR** call the `dates` variable like this, skipping the headers: `dates[1][0]`.

**Reference**

- [Sheet Class Apps Script - getRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column)